# Argument 2 to "knapsack" has incompatible type "Series[Any]"; expected "List[Union[int, float]]"

Tags: python, pandas, mypy

I created a function named `knapsack,` and I want to correctly type it, I created a new type Named number, but I think this is incorrect, because I am passing a pandas series to it

How to fix the typing?

```
knapsack(limit, df['latency'], df['amount'])
```

```
Number = Union[int, float]

def knapsack(W: int, wt: List[Number], value: List[Number]) -> int:
```

> Argument 2 to "knapsack" has incompatible type "Series[Any]"; expected "List[Union[int, float]]"

Comment: And why do you use `List`, if you're passing pandas `Series`?.. (also `int | float` simplifies to just `float`: for type-checking purpose, `int` is a subtype of `float` - although not a subclass).

Comment: I am using a List because I want more generic possible. Is it possible?

Comment: `List` is approximately opposite of "more generic", please have a look at [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) or [their `typing` alternatives for python before 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#abstract-base-classes), for your use case it should be a `Sequence` or maybe something even more generic (say, `Iterable`, if you convert this argument to the `list` or iterate over it)

Comment: If I change it to `Series[Any]` I got the error TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: What python and pandas version are you using?

Comment: pandas==1.5.1 with pandas-stubs==1.5.0.221012 mypy==0.982